# How to access Rails model in a rake file outside of rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

In order to access Rails models in a rake task you give `:environment` as a dependency. But what if you want to have dynamic descriptions of your task and they depend on some database date. For example:

```
end_date = Foo.end_date # the model foo provides some end date

desc "Do something after #{end_date}"
task bar: :environment do
  ...
end
```

I tried `Rake::Task[:environment].invoke`, but I get `Don't know how to build task 'environment'`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered that you can load up the rails environment a bit more manually. I just stick this at the top of the file containing the rake task:

```
# Pre-load the rails environment so we can dynamically create 
# these tasks. Your path may vary.

require File.expand_path('../../../config/environment', __FILE__)

# Eager load the models so I have access to them, this may be 
# different in your environment.

Zeitwerk::Loader.eager_load_all
```

Comment: Take into account you can always write a Ruby script and execute it with `bin/rails runner`. That way it all works out of the box.